# How to get api_token when user login in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, api, eloquent, laravel-5, restful-authentication

I am using token guard to authenticate users using api_token passed in post request. But I am unable to retrieve api_token using token guard guard. I thought of getting user from `retrieveByCredentials($credentials)` and check for password using `validateCredentials($user, $credentials)` which are in `EloquentUserProvider.php`, but to access them I have to use `Auth::guard('api')->provider` where provider is a protected property. So I have to manually do that. Is there any simple procedure to get the api_token when login is implemented.

My login method in AuthController.php

```
public function api_login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), ['email' => 'required', 'password' => 'required']);

        $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

        $user = Auth::guard('api')->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);
        if(is_null($user)) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => [
                    'message' => 'Your email is not registered yet',
                    'status_code' => 40
                ]
            ]);
        } elseif(Auth::guard('api')->provider->validateCredentials($user, $credentials)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => [
                    'api_token' => Auth::guard('api')->user()->api_token,
                    'message' => 'Login successful', 
                    'status_code' => 200
                ]
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'error' => [
                'message' => 'Login failed', 
                'status_code' => 20
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

Note: I used provider, but I can't use that as it is a protected property.

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 5.2, there are 2 authentication guard `'web'` and `'api'`, they are implemented in `SessionGuard` and `TokenGuard` respectively, as you know.

`TokenGuard` doesn't have modules for checking validation with email and password, it only checks validity using `api_token`. 
But `SessionGuard` does; `attempt()` method.

So we can use web guard for login only, and can use `'auth:api'` middleware for the other apis.

Here is login function, which can be implemented easily.

```
public function api_login(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), ['email' => 'required', 'password' => 'required']);

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

    // only web guard can validate with credentials
    $guard = Auth::guard('web');

    if ($guard->attempt($credentials)) {

        // maybe you can generate api_token again here

        return response()->json([
            'success' => [
                'api_token' => $guard->user()->api_token,
                'message' => 'Login successful', 
                'status_code' => 200
            ]
        ]);
    } 
    else {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => [
                'message' => 'Login failed', 
                'status_code' => 200
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```